# Django JWT HTTP Authorization not passing

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I am trying to use JWT token authentication with Django rest framework. I was able to successfully get the access and refresh token. And I made sure that the token is valid. But when I try to access some protected apiview with the access token. It says

`{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}.`

```
curl -H "Authorization: JWT eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNTE0MzQzNzcxLCJqdGkiOiIwYmE5YTcxZTJmMzQ0YmRmOTM1ZWQ3MTU3ZmI2NDkyZiIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjh9.dI3t8yvNe2Z7MKXojGvFpq_Etf1cLg8QSYsNobJ6jQ0" http://localhost:8000/users/me/
```

However, on server side I did get the request.META with a `HTTP_AUTHORIZAITON` field that contains the above token.

I'm currently developing on localhost instead of Apache, with following files and configurations:

In views.py:

```
class GetMyInfo(views.APIView):

 def get(self,request):
  print(request.META)
  user = request.user
  profile = user.profile
  profile_serializer = ProfileSerializer(instance = profile)
  return Response(profile_serializer.data, status = HTTP_200_OK)
```

In url.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^api/$', get_schema_view()),
    re_path(r'^api/auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    re_path(r'^api/auth/token/obtain/$', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name = 'token_obtain_pair'),
    re_path(r'^api/auth/token/refresh/$', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name = 'token_refresh'),
    re_path(r'^api/auth/token/verify/$', TokenVerifyView.as_view(), name = 'token_verify'),
    #re_path(r'^api-token-auth/', authviews.obtain_auth_token, name = 'obtain_auth_token'),
    re_path(r'^users/$', views.CreateUser.as_view(), name = 'register'),
    re_path(r'users/(?P<uuid>[0-9a-f-]+)/$', views.GetUserInfo.as_view(), name = 'info'),
    re_path(r'users/me/$', views.GetMyInfo.as_view(), name = 'myinfo'),
]
```

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'api'
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES':(
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES':(
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        #'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        #'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        #'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ),
    'TEST_REQUEST_DEFAULT_FORMAT': 'json',
}


AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'api.User'
```

In models.py:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance = None, created = False, **kwargs):
 if created:
  Token.objects.create(user = instance)

class User(AbstractUser):
 uuid = models.UUIDField(default = uuid.uuid4, unique = True)

class Profile(models.Model):
 owner = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
 on_delete = models.CASCADE, 
 primary_key = True,
 related_name = 'profile')
 displayname = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
 location = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = True)
 bio = models.CharField(max_length = 500, null = True)
 relationships = models.ManyToManyField('self', 
 through = 'Followings', 
 symmetrical = False,
 related_name = 'related_to')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I see you are using `rest_framework_simplejwt` package to handle JWT authentication.

A sample from the docs specify you should use:
`Authorization: Bearer <token>` to access protected views.

So instead of

```
curl -H "Authorization: JWT eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNTE0MzQzNzcxLCJqdGkiOiIwYmE5YTcxZTJmMzQ0YmRmOTM1ZWQ3MTU3ZmI2NDkyZiIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjh9.dI3t8yvNe2Z7MKXojGvFpq_Etf1cLg8QSYsNobJ6jQ0" http://localhost:8000/users/me/
```

use:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNTE0MzQzNzcxLCJqdGkiOiIwYmE5YTcxZTJmMzQ0YmRmOTM1ZWQ3MTU3ZmI2NDkyZiIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjh9.dI3t8yvNe2Z7MKXojGvFpq_Etf1cLg8QSYsNobJ6jQ0" http://localhost:8000/users/me/
```

Comment: If you want to use `JWT`, you should specify it in the configuration:
`SIMPLE_JWT = {'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ['JWT']}`